# Linq to SQL : How to do WHERE [Column] = Element in LIST ?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

First of all, i've seen many posts like mine but I didn't find the answer.

So, I try to find the equivalent of the "IN" clause for an linq to SQL request and i find something :

```
    IList<int> listClientId = GetAllClientIdByRegionLPS(statutRegion);
    if (!statutRegion.Equals(""))
        q = q.Where(p => listClientId.Contains((int)p.ClientId));
```

But that makes me an error : 
"'boolean contains(int32)' has no supported translation to sql"

What i want to do : 
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE [CONDITIONS]
AND (id == 1 OR id ==2 OR id==3 OR ...)

Let's see my code :

```
public IList<Appel> GetAllCourants(string Filter, int? StatutFacturation, int? statutDemande, int? statutPro, string statutRegion)
    {
        var q = from p in DbContext.Appels
                where (p.Client.Nom.Contains(Filter) || p.AppelId.ToString().Contains(Filter) || (p.Materiel.Modele1.Nom + " #" + p.Materiel.NumeroSerie).Contains(Filter) || p.ContactClient.Nom.Contains(Filter) || p.ContactClient.Prenom.Contains(Filter) || p.Dossier.Contains(Filter) || p.Client.CodePostal.Contains(Filter) || p.Client.Ville.Contains(Filter) || p.NumDevis.Contains(Filter))
                select p;
        q = q.Where(p => p.StatutAppelId == 1 || p.StatutAppelId == 9 || p.StatutAppelId == 10 || p.StatutAppelId == 13 || p.StatutAppelId == 14 || p.StatutAppelId == 15 || p.StatutAppelId == 16 || p.StatutAppelId == 17 || p.StatutAppelId == 18);

        if (StatutFacturation.HasValue)
            q = q.Where(p => p.Facturable == StatutFacturation.Value);

        if (statutDemande.HasValue)
            q = q.Where(p => p.StatutDemandePiece == statutDemande.Value);

        if (statutPro.HasValue)
            q = q.Where(p => p.Depot == statutPro.Value);
        //This makes me troubles
        IList<int> listClientId = GetAllClientIdByRegionLPS(statutRegion);
        if (!statutRegion.Equals(""))
            q = q.Where(p => listClientId.Contains((int)p.ClientId)); /*Try to do p.ClientId = listClientId*/

        var ret = q.Select(p => Deserialize<Generated.Appel>(p)).ToList();
        return ret;
    }
```

How can I fixe it ?

Thanks a lot in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
IList<int> listClientId = GetAllClientIdByRegionLPS(statutRegion);
```

to

```
List<int> listClientId = GetAllClientIdByRegionLPS(statutRegion);
```